# Explanation of a basic multithreading program in C using Pthread

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to learn multithreading programming in C and trying to understand basic program. I could not understand the runner function and why is it returning a pointer to a type void and passing a parameter which is also a pointer to void. Also , I could not understand the parameters of main.

```
int sum; / this data is shared by the thread(s) 
void *runner(void *param); / the thread 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 pthread_t tid; / the thread identifier /
 pthread.attr_t attr; / set of thread attributes /
if (argc != 2) {
fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
return -1;
}
if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
fprintf(stderr,"%d must be >= 0\n",atoi(argv[1]));
return -1;
/ get the default attributes /
pthread.attr.init (&attr) ;
/ create the thread /
pthread^create(&tid,&attr,runner,argv[1]);
/ wait for the thread to exit /
pthread_join (tid, NULL) ;
printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
/ The thread will begin control in this function /
void *runner(void *param)
{<br />
int i, upper = atoi(param);
sum = 0;<br />
for (i = 1; i <= upper; i
sum += i;
pthread_exit (0) ;
```

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code - this needs to be formatted more clearly.

Comment: please fix the code in a comprehensible way

Comment: There doesn't seem to a concrete question, here. Please browse the web  for explanations as you are looking for. There is plenty around on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to `main` first.  `argc` is the number of command-line parameters, including the program name. `argv` is an array of pointers to zero-delimited strings, which are the parameters themselves.  So, if you run your program from the command-line like this:

```
myprog x y z
```

Then `argc` will be 4, `argv` will look like this:

```
argv[0]: "myprog"
argv[1]: "x"
argv[2]: "y"
argv[3]: "z"
argv[4]: ""
```

The final element should be an empty string.  The exact format of the first element (program name) varies depending on the operating system and the exact way the program is called.

Your `runner` function is a type of function sometimes generally known as a *callback*.  It is called by someone else (the pthread library).  In order for someone else to call your function, it has to know it's return type and parameters, so these are fixed, even when they are not used.

So `runner` has to return a `void *` (untyped pointer) and take a `void *` parameter, even when it does not actually use either (it can return `NULL`).  It is that way because that is what the pthread library expects.